# Binding is not updating multiple UI elements

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding

I have buttons on my Silverlight page where the opacity is bound to one of two properties on my ViewModel.  I'm using the button command that changes the properties, in theory to affect all buttons bound to that property, but the only control that gets affected is the button that initiates the command (any one of them).

Any ideas on why the additional bindings don't work?

The whole thing is actually a little more complex where the buttons are on a Control with the bindings as DependencyProperties mapping back to the VM, and the bound properties are going through a ValueConverter.

Comment: As you say "in theory" it should work, but would be impossible to answer with out a sample that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  The opacity binding wasn't working, but what was happening was the button was disabling itself based on the predicate I had set in the RelayCommand.  It looked like the effect I wanted, but only affected the button being pressed because each button was bound to a seperate ICommand.

I changed it to remove change the binding from the OpacityProperty to the IsEnabledProperty, and removed the predicate from the RelayCommand declaration.  It all works now as intended.

I don't know why the button would change to a disabled view when it checks the predicate (and finds it false), but never change back if the condition changes.  Odd.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to raise the [INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event for the properties that are changing. This will let the controls that are bound to them know that there is a change and that they need to come back and get the latest value.

Comment: Already being done.  That's how the button being pressed has it's opacity being changed.  It's just not happening for the other buttons bound to the same VM property.